# Mobile first Session Timeout call back function?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid

I'm implementing an adapter base authentication and trying the session timeout functionality in "worklight.properties"

Is there a callback function for serverSessionTimeout? I want to get go back to the login screen when this happens.

I'm only able to get a response is true in isCustomResponse meaning it will ask user to key in the login details (e.g. "credentialsRequired") again. In which I can't differentiate whether this is a first time login or session timeout.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_miscellaneous_settings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no callback for it. This needs to be handled in the same place in your code where you are checking for the user credentials.

Meaning:

1. Application launches > user reaches the login screen
2. User log-ins (a request to a protected resource is made, a challenge is sent to the client, the check is for the adapter to process and verify user credentials for example, the response/reply to the check is sent to the server, the server approves, the client proceeds to display whatever is after the login screen
3. A timeout is reached, the server knows this and sends a challenge again to the client

In this same code piece, if a challenge is sent to the client, you need to ensure to change the client UI to display the login form.

Basically I don't think you need to differentiate, but rather treat them the same?
At least that's my interpretation/understanding.

I think this is what is done in the adapter-based authentication sample application. [Have you checked it](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/)?

Comment: I've referred to the sample application before. Maybe because I'm displaying the login screen prior to getting the data which makes things a little confusing to me. Should be able to sort it out base on your advice. Thanks @IdanAdar